# What happens if i delete goals on CM?

Tags: wffm, goals

what happens when i delete Web-forms and it goals on CM? 
is there any impact in analytic or else?
I don't need the goals and that Web-forms anymore, because its not used anymore and it become junk on my CM so i want to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no impact on the analytics or elsewhere as long it is not being referenced in the code. Once you delete it from CM, on CD also it will get removed. Since there will be no content / forms associated with the goals, nothing will trigger.

Analytics data that have already been captured will still remain. However, as new data is being captured in the analytics table, the goals that have been deleted will become old and may not come up based on the amount of analytics data captured.

Comment: oh thanks, is there any impact on visitor value?

Comment: No the visitor value is already in the database but note that tomorrow if you recreate the goals, it will have another Id. So you may need to migrate the data to map the new goal Id